# Cannot download with right format an excel file F#

Tags: http, f#

I have the following part of code:

```
let client = new WebClient()
let url = "https://..."
client.DownloadFile(Url, filename)                                                    
client.Dispose()
```

In which code i am performing a `HttpGet` method in which method i get a file `excel` with some data. 
The method is executed correctly because i get my excel file.

The problem is that the content of my file excel is like this: 
[image]

I think its because i don't pass `ContentType:"application/vnd.ms-excel"`

So anyone can help how can I pass that `ContentType` in my Client in F# ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "all in binary"? How is that determined?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin lets say that data in excel is not readable. I am not sure if was binary or raw data

Comment: What do you mean by "not readable"?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin updated

Comment: @FyodorSoikin The picture is an example of what i see. It is not the actual excel file

Comment: The picture indicates that you're looking at a file named `libtheora.dll`. Is that where you're saving the download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add HTTP headers to a request made using `WebClient`, use the `Headers` property:

```
let client = new WebClient()
let url = "https://..."
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/vnd.ms-excel")
client.DownloadFile(Url, filename)
```

In your case, I think you need the `Accept` header (`Content-Type` is what the response should contain to tell you what you got).

That said, I'm not sure if this is the problem you are actually having - as noted in the comments, your screenshot shows a different file, so it is hard to tell what's wrong with the file you get from the download (maybe it's just somewhere else? or maybe the encoding is wrong?)

Comment: No i think you maybe be right. My screenshot file is an example of what i meant for "unreadable data" it is not the actual excel file because i was not on my pc